# How to show CSS grid in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using CSS grid which is working fine in all browsers and showing up as below;

[image]

But it is showing in internet explorer like this;

[image]

I am looking for solution to fix it but still unable to do that. I have used following css.

```css
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  column-gap: 20px;
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

And following html.

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
<div class="grid-item">10</div>
</div>
```

But still unable to find solution for internet explorer 11. Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: IE does not support modern CSS Grid layout. It does *partially* support an *older* version, but you also have to use `-ms-` vendor prefixes for it, including `display: -ms-grid`.

Comment: [Grid support in internet exploder](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid)